# Why do i have mouse cursor artifacts on portrait monitor setup?

Tags: windows, delphi, cursor, nvidia, monitor

I have a delphi application that loads custom mouse cursors by using `LoadImage(Hinstance, PWideChar(Name), IMAGE_CURSOR, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);`. These custom cursors have a size of 32x32, 48x48 or 64x64, depending of the users choice. If i load a custom cursor and move the mouse outside the application, the cursor changes to the windows default (arrow) one. But this arrow now has artifacts on the bottom side of the cursor.
Also the artifacts change depending on the custom cursor previously loaded and the size it includes in the, e.g. 64x64 rect.

I was trying to take a screenshot but the artifacts do not appear on it. So i painted the phenomenon to give you a clue how it looks like.

[image]

What i have found so far. All points on the following list must be applied:

- It only happens when the custom mouse cursor is > 32x32.
- It only happens on a monitor setup in portrait mode.
- It only happens if the mouse shadow is active.
- It only happens if the mouse trail is turned off.
- It only happens when having a NVIDIA graphics card.
- It only happens when the DPI setting is 100%.

The following code example shows the problem with the cursor. Just create a new VCL Form project and add it to the corresponding unit.

```
unit Unit6;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

const
   crMyCursor = 1;

type
  TForm6 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form6: TForm6;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm6.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.Cursors[crMyCursor] := LoadImage(Hinstance, PWideChar('MAINICON'), IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
  Screen.Cursor := crMyCursor;
end;

end.
```

**UPDATE:**
It used to be a problem in relation with NVIDIA graphic cards. The artifacts appear with the follwing graphic cards: GeForce 9600 GT, GeForce GT 630 and GeForce GTX 660. I also tested Intel Onboard graphic and ATI graphic cards and the artifacts do not appear with these setups.

So can anyone tell me why these artifacts appear and how i get rid of them?

Comment: Describe "portrait mode". You just turned the monitor on its side. Also, is this related to Delphi or do all apps behave the same way?

Comment: "Potrait mode" is the orientation of the monitor. You can change it in the windows control panel section "screen resolution". Actually this is not just a delphi problem as i have seen the phenomenon in other apps, like XN Resource Editor that i use to create a resource file to use the cursor in the delphi app.

Comment: *probably* the system has to switch from using a hardware cursor built into the graphics chip/subsystem to using a software cursor.

Comment: You might do better without the delphi tag

Comment: See also this [not quite the same but similar resolutions](http://superuser.com/questions/133370/mouse-icon-distorted-on-secondary-display) question from super user.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for the link but i think that is not really my kind of problem as long as i have an NVIDIA GeForce GT 630. And the point is, i do not want the user to turn of the mouse shadow or turn on the mouse trail. I thought that the issue could be solved programmatically or maybe miss something or use the `LoadImage` function wrong.

Comment: Switch your display adapter and driver and see if it happens.

Comment: @Sebastian - Dunno, I actually tried but couldn't duplicate it.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Are you sure your display was in portrait orientation?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz All points on the following list must be applied?
    It only happens when the custom mouse cursor is > 32x32.
    It only happens on a monitor setup in portrait mode.
    It only happens if the mouse shadow is active.
    It only happens if the mouse trail is turned off.

Comment: @Sebastian - Yes, I read the question before trying, all points as you stated. Running the case you supplied with XE2, cursor is also 48x48. Tried once again now without the wallpaper, no artifact. W7x64 with HD6850 (driver packaging 14.10) if you're interested..

Comment: Tried yet once more on the second monitor, which is on-board Intel HD 3000 (driver 9.17). Again no artifact.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Thanks for the hint. Finally i was wrong. It has something to do with the graphics card. I have updated my post with the new findings.

Comment: I've noticed this on a similar setup. I believe its a graphics driver bug in some older versions of the nVidia drivers. Since upgrading to more recent drivers sometime in the past year, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to bugs in the graphic drivers and [similar things occur for some ATI users](https://superuser.com/q/590569/241800) as well.
However, this is not a Delphi or even custom mouse issue.

I experienced the exact same phenomenon (weird line artifact following under the mouse cursor), but just on the desktop, on both of my side, portrait-flipped monitors (NB I'm running a gtx680, so your list isn't exhaustive either).

The issue is to do with shadowing. Both the [answers here](https://superuser.com/q/387809/241800) work, but obviously if you like shadows the current top answer (flipping the monitors back to landscape, then reverting at the `Keep these settings?` prompt) would suit you better.

Answer (score 0):

I actually was reintroduced to this issue following a rebuild. My solution for this was to enable "Display pointer trails" in Pointer Options in the Mouse Properties and setting the slider all the way to Short. After that, there were no more artifacts.

[Mouse Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxRhT.png)

The mouse trail is barely noticeable to me, and the afterimage of it helps me keep track of it across three monitors.